# Facebook like and share button slowing website

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I have setup a dynamic competition page where the query string determines what content you see.

For example (http://nectarfinance.com.au/dc=korinadrogan will show Korina's content, while no query string will show generic head office content).

The site (as is) is loading slowly, and I know it is happening because of the Facebook 'like and share' dynamic Facebook scripts on the page.

I was wondering if there is anyway to minify these script into one? Or if there is anyone to increase the load time of these scripts? or reduce the size of these scripts?

I'm not sure how to work around it as the files are externally hosted by Facebook.

I'll post the GTMetrix report in the answer below, as I can't post two links.

Thanks for your help

Comment: GTMEtrix report: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/nectarfinance.com.au/xin7Xisp